# Call a c++ activex dll from plain c code

Tags: c++, c, winapi, activex, mingw

I have a c++ active x dll which is built from visual studio 2005 and i need to call it from a "c" code which i has to be compiled in mingw32 compiler.

Is it possible to call a c++ active x dll from c or i have to convert the dll from activex to win32.

Please give me your suggestions.

Comment: Curious, why do you need to use only C? mingw32 can compile C++ just fine. If you have an existing C project, it might be simpler to add some C++ files to act as a wrapper to interact with the ActiveX/COM object.

Comment: I have a source project of c, for which c++ wrapper is tedious to write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveX is COM, and COM is essentially a C API (as it is a part of Win API which itself is a C API) so it is possible., but it requires a good understanding of COM. A good starting point can be found here:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C

Comment: anyway i have changed it to win32 as our other part of projects need win32 dll

Answer (score 1):

Active-X is the same as/built on COM (I won't go into the gory details). Since COM's very purpose is to allow cross language components, then yes, you can call COM objects from C.

However, I'm not sure how easy it will be, since you won't have any easy wizard's to import and create wrapper classes or other tooling support.

[Here is a blog](http://blog.devork.be/2009/12/calling-com-methods-in-c.html) that goes into some of the detail. Might be worth a look.

Comment: i didnt find the link for the blog, please check it